# Firefox/IE cached page on startup only shows AJAX content

Tags: javascript, ajax, caching, browser, startup

I have a webapp that uses AJAX calls to load HTML snippets in various places. Note that the webapp also simulates regular navigation with the use of history.pushState function (not sure it has anything to do with my problem but I still mention it).

**Problem:** 
Whenever I exit the browser with a tab displaying my webapp and restart it again, the browser does not trigger a regular HTTP request to load the whole page. It simply uses a cache mechanism to load the response of the latest HTTP request. In my case, if the last request happens to be an AJAX call, then the browser will only load the HTML snippet without css, js nor the rest of the HTML.
Note that the problem appears in Firefox. In IE, the whole page can be reloaded if you accept the execution of scripts when being prompted. Chrome works fine as it loads the entire page.

**Question:**
Is this a normal behavior and how can I prevent it (i.e. make it work like in Chrome)?

Thanks for helping!